# Reflection of a solid in 3D over a plane

Tags: linear-transformations, 3d

Below the star is reflected over the line. Clearly this is not same as rotating by 180 degrees. It seems one star is showing the front face and the other star is showing the back face. How does this information represented? The star in 2D has to move to 3D to finish the reflection.  Saying $A$ and $A'$ are at the same distance from the reflecting line seems insufficient to fully represent the reflection.

I have been watching [this](https://youtu.be/n6yeak4FITs?t=618) video and it kept me thinking about how a solid shape would look after reflection over a line/plane in 3D. It doesn't look that simple... Any help with explanation/good links appreciated very much. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: If you want to see what a 3d object looks like after reflection just look in a mirror.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting... but isn't the mirror  just reflecting the front surface of my body? Because light goes only from the surface of the body.. Then it's not really a reflection of solid. It's just a reflection of one of the surfaces of a solid, right?

Comment: True. Though if you looked at a transparent object in a mirror it would be a full reflection. There is a more formal definition of how reflection works if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Oh right. If different cross sections of my body are emitting different frequencies of light, and assuming the mirror reflects all frequencies; taking a picture of the mirror with different frequency cameras should give the full reflection XD

Comment: How did you come to decide that the reflection of the star shows its “back” face? A reflection reverses “front-to-back” relative to the reflecting surface, so if the above occurs within a plane, the reflection would still be showing the same face. If you embed this in three dimensional space, then the results are different depending on whether you’re reflecting in a plane mirror (which we’re seeing edge-on in your illustration), or in a line. The latter is equivalent to a rotation about the line, in which case we would see the “back” face of the star.

Comment: @amd so reflection is just a mathematical operation. In the sense that rotation and translation can be done by a `single` object; Imagine an object on a table. we can just move or rotate that object. But it's impossible to do the same with reflection. We have to destroy the original object into pieces and create a new one. I think I finally get this. Thanks!

Comment: @pooja That’s an interesting perspective!